# How can I create a scroll bar in customtkinter without textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, customtkinter

I want to create a scroll bar in custom tkinter, but I don't want to connect it to a text box and I want to connect it to a frame.

Comment: Frames aren't scrollable. You have to connect it to a widget that is scrollable. That usually means a `Canvas` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from customtkinter import *

def on_scrollbar_move(*args):
    canvas.yview(*args)

window = CTk()
window.geometry("400x300")

# Create a frame to hold the content
frame = CTkFrame(window)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a canvas widget
canvas = CTkCanvas(frame)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a scrollbar widget
scrollbar = CTkScrollbar(frame, command=on_scrollbar_move)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the content
content_frame = CTkFrame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=content_frame, anchor=NW)

# Add some widgets to the content frame
for i in range(50):
    label = CTkLabel(content_frame, text=f"Label {i}")
    label.pack()

# Configure the scrollable region of the canvas
content_frame.update_idletasks()  # Update the frame to get the correct size
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

window.mainloop()
```

[image]